# Prevent duplication of data in mysql database when entering from php

Tags: php, mysql

If i already have record with the exact same data in mysql database i dont want the php code to enter it  again.
The code i am using is

```
mysql_query(" ALTER TABLE tablename ADD UNIQUE INDEX(pageid, name) INSERT IGNORE INTO `tablename`  
VALUES ('2','3','4'));
```

It doesnt seem to work. What is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute this query from MySQL and create the index first.

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD UNIQUE INDEX(pageid, name);
```

Then you can perform the insert query from PHP

```
mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO `tablename`  VALUES ('2','3','4')");
```

Answer (score 2):

a) you need semicolon between queries
b) mysql_query does not support multiple queries
c) mysql_query has syntax errors should be `mysql_query(" ALTER TABLE tablename ADD UNIQUE INDEX(pageid, name) INSERT IGNORE INTO`tablename`VALUES ('2','3','4')");`

Comment: Execute `ALTER TABLE tablename ADD UNIQUE INDEX(pageid, name)` once  and then use `mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO tablename VALUES ('2','3','4')");` in your script

Answer (score 0):

Check the comment [HERE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) from David OBrien...

Basically since in MySQL **there is not** a `CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS` he suggest to use this kind of procedure :

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `create_index_if_not_exists`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`%` PROCEDURE `create_index_if_not_exists`(table_name_vc varchar(50), index_name_vc varchar(50), field_list_vc varchar(200))
SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN

set @Index_cnt = (
select  count(1) cnt
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS
WHERE   table_name = table_name_vc
and index_name = index_name_vc
);

IF ifnull(@Index_cnt,0) = 0 THEN set @index_sql = concat('Alter table ',table_name_vc,' ADD INDEX ',index_name_vc,'(',field_list_vc,');');

PREPARE stmt FROM @index_sql;
EXECUTE stmt;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END IF;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

and then call it like

```
call create_index_if_not_exists('tablename','indexname','thisfield,thatfield');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something similar like this:

```
$specifieddata = //the value(s) you want to check

$checkquery = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE yourdata = $specifieddata";
$resultcheck = mysql_query($checkquery);

//if the database contains the same values as given in $specifieddata; mysql_fetch_row should be 1 (or more)
if(mysql_fetch_row($resultcheck) >= 1)
{
    //your error(?) code
}

else
{
    //your INSERT code
}
```

Also, it might be worth noting you'll want to sanitize your input

The reason I recommend doing it this way is that you can give the user a (if you want detailed) error about what went wrong.